# Run rc.local only once Mongodb is running in CentOs 7

Tags: centos, centos7, mongodb, systemd, rc.local

I have the following script in my `rc.local`:

This runs the services on ports 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083. They are actually node servers that NEED mongod to startup.

So, I edited `/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service` and added:

```
After=network.target syslog.target mongod.service
```

But no: the scripts still fail because, at running time, they find that the database server is down.

What could I be doing wrong? How would I debug this?

**UPDATE**: Now that I added `After=`, the error is not the mongoDb connection (I was looking at old logs), but rather the fact that rc-local doesn't seem to be starting at all. Running manually `systemctl restart  rc-local.service` works though...

**UPDATE 2**: By taking `syslog.target` out, and so having:

```
After=network.target mongod.service
```

has the strange side effect that HALF of the servers (2 out of 4) start fine, and the other HALF fail to connect to the database. This makes me think that systemd runs mongodb, but it's not yet ready to take connections when rc-local is run

Comment: You really should write a proper systemd unit to start your node servers, rather than (ab)using rc.local.

Comment: If I have this problem with `rc.local`'s systemd unit, I will have the exact same issue with any "proper" systemd issue I will ever write

Comment: You can believe whatever you want to believe.

Comment: Please explain why another systemd unit wouldn't suffer from the problem `rc.local` suffers -- thanks!

Comment: Well you can't can you?

Answer (score -2):

As a workaround, why don't you set mongodb not to start using systemctl and set it to start in rclocal before the items you need?